# Switch to a different repository in Git

Tags: git, github

One situation in Git that I still find confusing is this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dude1/project
```

Whoops, that's not really the right version. I'll switch over:

```
$ git remote add dude2 https://github.com/dude2/project
$ git fetch dude2
$ git checkout dude2/master

Note: checking out 'dude2/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at f3o845a...
```

Hrm. I want `master` to refer to dude2/master.

```
$ git checkout -b master dude2/master

fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

Short of deleting the whole directory and starting again, how do I cleanly switch repositories?

Comment: Try `-B` instead of `-b` when you want to abandon whatever the branch used to refer to.

Comment: Great, thanks. Interestingly -B gives a message about how the different branches have diverged.

Comment: @SteveBennett then the two remotes do not have identical content in master. Your first `clone` copied the content of the first remote. When you switched master to the second remote, the differences are viewed as if you had created the differing commits yourself, "diverging" the master branch from the remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git you are not supposed to commit work on remote branches (you are supposed to do your work on *local* branches), that is why you are put in `'detached head' state` when you `checkout dude2/master`. Remote branches should contain copies of commits coming from remotes, never commits created locally.

As jthill suggests, the best way to force a switch of what `master` means is to

```
git checkout -B master dude2/master
```

The output should include

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from dude2.
```

Indicating that your master is now tracking the changes of a different remote master.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking this through, the obvious answer is:

First `git checkout dude2/master` as above. Then:

```
$ git branch -d master
warning: deleting branch 'master' that has been merged to
     'refs/remotes/dude1/master', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch master (was f30845a).

$ git checkout -b master dude2/master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from dude2.
Switched to a new branch 'dude2'
```

I have no idea what the warning when you delete the master is meant to mean though.